# Multithreading iteration in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new in c++ and I'm trying to iterate over the result of `equal_range(key)` applied to a multimap which is an Iterator. Right now, I'm able to iterate over the result using a for loop and the `result.first` and `result.second` values, like in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::multimap<char,int> mymm;

  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('a',10));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',20));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',30));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',40));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',50));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',60));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('d',60));


  auto ret = mymm.equal_range('b');
  for (auto it=ret.first; it!=ret.second; ++it)
      std::cout << ' ' << it->second;

}
```

In my actual case, I need to iterate faster (over thousands of rows in a short period of time), so I'm trying to iterate using multiple threads. However, I'm not able to do this because my idea was to split the iterator in different parts and then iterate over each part in different threads. But this is not possible because I can't do something like `it = it + 10` to start iterating over different positions.

So essentially I need to split a range of non-random access iterators into multiple smaller ranges. Is there any safe way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate faster?  How many matching keys are you expecting?  With this small example the cost of spinning up new threads will significantly outweigh any potential gains.

Comment: I think a better way of asking is "Splitting a range of non-random access iterators into multiple smaller ranges" or something like that. The question is not inherently related to multithreading.

Comment: @0x5453 that is just an example. I need to iterate over thousands of keys. I have updated the question.

Comment: Beware that once you have several smaller ranges, you still have to be careful about synchronizing the results of your individual threads.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in a comment, your question boils down to "How to split a range of non-random access iterators into multiple smaller ranges". Once you got that you can hand those smaller ranges to multiple threads.

You cannot `it + 10` when `it` is not a random access iterator. You can however, use `std::advance` to advance the iterator.

To illustrate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template <typename IT>
std::vector<IT> split_range(IT begin, IT end,size_t chunksize){
    std::vector<IT> result;
    auto it = begin;
    result.push_back(it);
    size_t total = 0;
    size_t size = std::distance(begin,end);
    while (total + chunksize < size){
        std::advance(it,chunksize);
        result.push_back(it);
        total += chunksize;
    }
    if (it != end) result.push_back(end);
    return result; 
}



int main ()
{
  std::multimap<char,int> mymm;

  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('a',10));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',20));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',30));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',40));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',50));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',60));
  mymm.insert(std::pair<char,int>('d',60));


  auto ret = mymm.equal_range('b');
  
  auto splitted = split_range(ret.first,ret.second,1);
  for (auto it = splitted.begin(); std::next(it) != splitted.end(); ++it){
       std::cout << "printing one chunk\n";
       for (auto it2 = *it; it2 != *std::next(it); ++it2){
           std::cout << ' ' << it2->second << "\n";
       }
  }
}
```

`split_range` is probably not the most efficient. `std::advance` has a price, you need to iterate the whole range once in a single thread. And also `std::distance` is not for free on non-random access iterators (basically requiring iterating the whole range a second time). Though once you have splitted the range you can use multiple threads to process the subranges in parallel.

Comment: It is important  to note that a single thread will still have to iterate over the whole range, because `std::advance` has linear complexity. Its just that the work that thread has to do is presumably much less than what actually has to be done to each element.

Comment: @FrancoisAndrieux jup, just added a note. I assumed that OP is aware of overhead and the workload is sufficient to justify the initial overhead

Answer (score 1):

One way to parallelize the work is to use the [`<execution>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/execution) policies added in C++17.

Used with [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) it could look like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::multimap<char, int> mymm;

    mymm.insert(std::pair<char, int>('a', 10));
    mymm.insert(std::pair<char, int>('b', 20));
    mymm.insert(std::pair<char, int>('b', 30));
    mymm.insert(std::pair<char, int>('b', 40));
    mymm.insert(std::pair<char, int>('c', 50));
    mymm.insert(std::pair<char, int>('c', 60));
    mymm.insert(std::pair<char, int>('d', 60));

    auto [begin, end] = mymm.equal_range('b');

    std::for_each(std::execution::par, begin, end,
        [](const auto& p)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << p.second;
        }
    );
}
```